# Freemember login errors with Transcribe

Tags: freemember, transcribe

I am using EE version 2.9.2, transcribe 1.6.1 and Freemember 2.3.2

I have a login form which works fine in the original language with error_handling set to inline.  However, when I viewed in the translated language the error_handling parameter causes the form to redirect to the home page without the language prefix when a bad username is entered.

If I remove error_handling-"inline" the problem disappears but of course the error shown is in the original language not the desired one.

Does anyone know how to fix this?
Cheers

Answer (score 1):

This looks to be a bug within FreeMember, as a Transcribed entry is much like any other normal entry.

I would try logging the bug over at [FreeMembers Issue Queue](https://github.com/devdemon/freemember/issues), to try and get a 1st aprty response. Otherwise stay posted, I don't have a suitable test set up so I couldn't debug this for you, but there's pleanty of transcribe/freemember users on here...

Comment: Ok, I too have now encountered this issue. It's actaully a bug in Transcribe. I just tried implimenting FreeMember Registration form and was getting a wierd (corrupt) error message when using inline_errors. Uninstalling Transcribe fixed everything. It seems that Transcribe does something funky with `ee()->core->generate_page()`

Comment: I also get the same issue with `ee()->core->generate_page()`. Any solutions ?

Comment: This is quite an old item, it mightbe worth checking Transcribe's changelog to see if they've fixed anything like this.might be worth trying (as concept) users solution above too...

Comment: Thanks for the quick response mate. I am using latest versions of Smart members and Transcribe. I tries solution of above answer and it working too. But problem is, When I submit the form and if there is any errors, It will show on gray EE screen not Inline..

Answer (score 1):

Im a little late to the party, but I just spent a day tracking down the cause of this bug. The issue is that transmit deals with ACT actions differently to normal GET requests.

In `ext.transcribe.php` on about line `995` there is a line that looks like this...

`if($submitted_action_id_data->class != 'Forms')`

By changing this to ...

`if(!in_array($submitted_action_id_data->class, ['Forms', 'Freemember']))`

... We can stop Transcribe from exiting early for POST Actions.

I hope this helps someone.

Comment: Hello, I found this helpful in EE3. I am using transcribe with smart members PRO. and `if(!in_array($submitted_action_id_data->class, ['Forms', 'Smart_members']))` helps me.. But it shows errors in gray error box not inline. Any solutions?